# Sprite not moving when using a function from another class SFML c++

Tags: c++, sfml, sprite

I have a Game.cpp, and I am calling a update function in my Player class. In my player update Function I have it to check for keyboard input, and it seems to work, but whenever I try to call the .move() function, it seems to not work. I get no errors either. I am new to sfml, and decent with c++. Help is appreciated!

```
#include "Player.h"


Player::Player(void):
    vel(0),
    maxvel(100)
{
    Load("Assets/sss.png",true);
}

void Player::Update(sf::Sprite& p)
{
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
    {
        moveObject(-3,0, p);
    }
    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
    {
        moveObject(-3,0, p);
    }
}


Player::~Player(void)
{
}
```

This is the GameObject cpp

```
#include "GameObject.h"
#include <iostream>


GameObject::GameObject(void)
{
    isLoaded = false;
}

void GameObject::Load(std::string flname, bool isPlayer)
{
    if(!tex.loadFromFile(flname))
    {
        EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
    {
        if(isPlayer)
        {
            if(!tex.loadFromFile(flname, sf::IntRect(0,0,33,33)))
            {
                EXIT_FAILURE;   
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Loading image" << "\n";
                filename = flname;
                spr.setTexture(tex);
                isLoaded = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Loading image" << "\n";
            filename = flname;
            spr.setTexture(tex);
            isLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}

void GameObject::Draw(sf::RenderWindow & window)
{
    if(isLoaded)
    {
        window.draw(spr);
        window.display();
        std::cout << "Sprite drew" << "\n";
    }
}

void GameObject::setPos(float x, float y)
{
    if(isLoaded)
    {
        spr.setPosition(x,y);
    }
}

sf::Vector2f GameObject::GetObjPos()
{
    return spr.getPosition();
}


sf::Sprite& GameObject::getSprite()
{
    return spr;
}

void GameObject::moveObject(float x, float y, sf::Sprite& sp)
{
    sp.move(x, y);
}


GameObject::~GameObject(void)
{
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: What code in particular?

Comment: Well, you just told us about some of your classes.. I doubt anyone will be able to help without any further information. For starters, what about the place where you call that `move` function?

Comment: Just edited in my player class, I doubt that is enough to get help from. I'll add my others as well.

Comment: What's the use of all the pseudo-OO cargo cult? `void GameObject::moveObject(float x, float y, sf::Sprite& sp)
{
    sp.move(x, y);
}` - what's the use? Does `GameObject` collect fees for any call that it passes on to sprites?

Comment: Well hard to tell. Do you pass the correct `Sprite` to the `Update`-function?

Comment: Why pass a sprite reference to the moveObject function instead of just using the member sprite spr directly as with all the other functions in GameObject?

Answer (score 1):

From the code shown you should re-write moveObject as

```
void GameObject::moveObject(float x, float y)
{
    spr.move(x, y);
}
```

where spr is the member variable of GameObject used elsewhere in the class

Answer (score 0):

Change your moveObject function to this

```
void GameObject::moveObject(float x, floaty)
{
    spr.setPosition(x, y);
}
```

If you need to get the x and y position make a get method for the spr or make it public